# link button to view controller programmatically xcode

Tags: objective-c

I am starting with xcode

how I can bind a button to a view controller programmatically?

ctrl + drag cursor already I have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are the beginning of Xcode. So follow below steps:-

1) create class inheriting with `NSViewController`.

2) Implement this below two methods inside `yourCustomClassViewCotroller`:-

```
-(NSString*)nibName
{
return @"yourViewContollerNibName"
}
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
//use akash code here for creating the button programmatically.
//And also while adding subview button to view. Replace view to self.view
}
```

3)Now in you other class lets say `appDelegate.h` declare properties method of your `yourCustomClassViewCotroller` like that below:-

```
@properties(nonAtomic,strong)yourCustomClassViewCotroller *yourVw;
```

4)Now in `appdelegate.m` file just load the viewcontroller class inside your method and then add to the window like that below:-

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
self.yourVw=[NSViewController alloc]initWithNibName:yourViewContollerNibName bundle:nil];
[_window setContentView:self.yourVw.view];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self 
       action:@selector(buttonAction:)   //action method 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Show View" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(50.0, 100.0, 100.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

There are plenty of examples out there if you try harder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are using Storyboards. If not, I recommend you do!

In Storyboard, moving between view controllers is handled by segues. Segues can be created by CTRL+Dragging between either an button and a view controller or two view controllers.

CTRL+Dragging between a button and a view controller automatically binds the touch of the button to the segue.

If you CTRL+Drag between two view controllers, it will only create a segue. To make the switch actually happen, you have to perform the segue with the method: `- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender`

Here is an example of how to perform a segue:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"unique segue identifier" sender:self];
```

When an segue is created in a storyboard, it creates a arrow between the two view controllers like this:
[image: Storyboard segue]

This is a segue and if you press it you can change the segue's identifier and also the animation.

Note: If I'm not mistaken, if you select the segue style "Push" you have to implement an navigation controller.

Hope it helps, cheers!

Comment: @JoseVega If you find this to be the correct answer, please mark it as correct. :)